# Roblox studio How to make a frame bob up and down then land in a certain position

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to make a frame that bobs up and down when an event is triggered (already worked the event out and it works perfectly) however i have no idea how to work with frames and i would really like to make the frame do the effect mentioned above, an additional thing is can it then after another event is triggered slide down and off the screen?

Answer (score 1):

Heyo, the Developer Hub has great [tutorials for working with with Frames and Guis](https://developer.roblox.com/articles/Fundamentals-of-Scripting-with-GUIs)!
It sounds like [TweenService](https://developer.roblox.com/api-reference/class/TweenService) is the thing that will solve your problem!

I don't know what signal you're tapping into but here's a simple example of the thing you want to do :

1) Create a ScreenGui in StarterGui.

2) Add a TextButton to the ScreenGui, we'll listen for clicks on this to toggle the frame open and close.

3) Add a Frame to the ScreenGui, add some stuff to it. Customize it, move it around.

4) Add a LocalScript to the ScreenGui. Add this to the script...

```
-- grab some UI Elements
local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")
local btn = script.Parent.TextButton
local testFrame = script.Parent.Frame

-- make some variables
local isVisible = false
local currentTween
local onscreenPos = testFrame.Position
local offscreenPos = UDim2.new(onscreenPos.X.Scale - 1,
    onscreenPos.X.Offset,
    onscreenPos.Y.Scale,
    onscreenPos.Y.Offset)

-- make a helper function for animating the frame
local function tweenToPos(thing, target)
    local tweenInfo = TweenInfo.new(0.5,  -- how long should this play (seconds)
        Enum.EasingStyle.Bounce, -- << This will give you the bounce in look
        Enum.EasingDirection.Out,
        0, -- number of times to repeat
        false, -- reverses
        0) -- how many seconds to delay the animation

    local propertyTable = {
        Position = target,
    }
    local tween = TweenService:Create(thing, tweenInfo, propertyTable)
    return tween
end

-- move the frame off-screen to begin with
testFrame.Position = offscreenPos

-- connect to the button and toggle between on/offscreen
btn.Activated:Connect(function(inputObj)
    -- if the tween is already running, cancel it
    if currentTween then
        if currentTween.PlaybackState == Enum.PlaybackState.Playing
            or currentTween.PlaybackState == Enum.PlaybackState.Delayed
            or currentTween.PlaybackState == Enum.PlaybackState.Paused then
            currentTween:Cancel()
        end
    end

    -- create a new tween to animate the frame
    if isVisible then
         currentTween = tweenToPos(testFrame, offscreenPos)
    else
         currentTween = tweenToPos(testFrame, onscreenPos)
    end

    -- play the animation
    currentTween:Play()

    -- toggle which tween to use next
    isVisible = not isVisible
end)
```

This should have a nice bounce effect for going in and out. You can swap out the `btn.Activated:Connect` with whatever signal you were listening to and this should work just fine.

Hope this helped!

Comment: The event i am trying to fire is when the mouse hovers over the screen GUI (if thats even possible). the position i am trying to get it to is from 0,0,0.914,0 to 0,0,0.443,0. the reason i am giving you the details is because i cannot simply do it myself, I'm confused. I tried to watch a YouTube video explaining it but it is nothing like what you wrote. @Kylaa

Comment: @Wootsoop, I've added a second answer that shows how to listen for Mouse Events and I've updated to target positions too. Let me know if that helps clear up any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Heyo, since you're trying to animate when a user hovers over a frame, follow these steps...

1) Create a ScreenGui in StarterGui.

2) Add a Frame to the ScreenGui, change its name to HoverFrame, we'll listen for mouse events on this to toggle the animation states.

3) Add another Frame to the ScreenGui, change its name to TweenFrame, add some stuff to it. Customize it, move it around, this is what we'll animate around the screen.

4) Add a LocalScript to the ScreenGui. Double click to open it, and add this to the script...

```
-- grab some UI Elements
local hoverFrame = script.Parent.HoverFrame
local testFrame = script.Parent.TweenFrame

-- make some variables
local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")
local currentTween
local onscreenPos = UDim2.new(0,0,0.443,0)
local offscreenPos = UDim2.new(0,0,0.914,0)

-- make a helper function for animating the frame
local function tweenToPos(thing, target)
    local tweenInfo = TweenInfo.new(0.5,  -- how long should this play (seconds)
        Enum.EasingStyle.Bounce, -- << This will give you the bounce in look
        Enum.EasingDirection.Out,
        0, -- number of times to repeat
        false, -- reverses
        0) -- how many seconds to delay the animation

    local propertyTable = {
        Position = target,
    }
    local tween = TweenService:Create(thing, tweenInfo, propertyTable)
    return tween
end

-- make another helper function for handling the animation tween
local function cancelTweenIfPlaying()
    if currentTween then
        if currentTween.PlaybackState == Enum.PlaybackState.Playing
            or currentTween.PlaybackState == Enum.PlaybackState.Delayed
            or currentTween.PlaybackState == Enum.PlaybackState.Paused then
            currentTween:Cancel()
        end
    end
end


-- listen for when the mouse hovers over the button, and animate the frame
hoverFrame.MouseEnter:Connect(function(x, y)
    -- if there is an animation playing, cancel it.
    cancelTweenIfPlaying()

    -- animate the frame to center stage
    currentTween = tweenToPos(testFrame, onscreenPos)
    currentTween:Play()
end)

-- listen for when the mouse stops hovering over the button
hoverFrame.MouseLeave:Connect(function(x, y)
    -- if the tween is already running, cancel it
    cancelTweenIfPlaying()

    -- animate to offscreen
    currentTween = tweenToPos(testFrame, offscreenPos)
    currentTween:Play()
end)
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: It works perfectly with the animation; however when it is ran the HoverFrame doesn't move meaning that there is only one place to detect, I tried to fix it by adding   a seperate script that reverses the roles of HoverFrame and TweenFrame but it just made it move back and forth. I'm sorry if this is annoying to you by making you make another answer. @Kylaa

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's wrong.
hoverFrame was just a frame that we would connect events to, and in this example, it wasn't meant to move. You don't have to use hoverFrame, you could connect these same functions to any gui element.
And your original question was how to make a frame animate onto the screen. My examples were just a way to show how to use TweenService to get there.